# How to save a session on Matlab

Tags: matlab

I was trying to save my Matlab variables and environment into a session so that next time I can directly load them without repeating the codes. I know how to save the Workspace variables but their way of saving a session doesn't work. It's said to be File -> Save to a session. But I couldn't find the button "File".

Any thoughts?

Comment: What else is there besides variables to save? The command `save`, by itself, saves all variables to a standard file (I think it's `matlab.mat` or something like that). `load` by itself loads that file again.

Comment: Saving *sessions* appears to be a specific option associated with various tools, such as [`SPTool` for the Signal Processing Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ug/saving-and-loading-sessions.html). In other words, it doesn't apply to the MATLAB workspace.

Comment: In addition to the variables, I guess the paths to the folders containing scripts are also worth saving, just like Python environment paths. Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

OK Actually I figured out an alternative solution. I realized that I could save all the Workspace variables. But my variables are too huge. So I ended up saving all my commands in a .m script file. 
So next time when I want to resume my work, I just type the name of that script file to run all the useful commands to create the working variables and set up the script paths I need.